# Did Ferenc Fricsay perform Dvorak's 8th Symphony?

Tags: classical-music

I love Fricsay's unusual sound, but I have only been able to find a recording of his Dvorak 9th 'New World'. Is anyone aware of a recording of the eighth? Or, perhaps an alternative to beat Harnoncourt's conducting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of Fricsay having recorded any performances of the 8th.

Szell with Cleveland, Karajan with Berlin, Alsop with Baltimore, Dohnanyi with Cleveland, and Neumann with the Czech Philharmonic are all in my collection, but my personal favorite is Suitner with the Staatskapelle Berlin.

(And a personal plug for one of my favorite symphonies ever: don't neglect Dvorak 7!)